# django-passwords is not working

Tags: django, passwords

I am trying to use the django app - https://github.com/dstufft/django-passwords, to set up password strength checking for django passwords. Here are things i have done till now:

1. Installed django-passwords with

   ```
   pip install django-passwords
   ```
2. Added 'passwords' to INSTALLED_APPS
3. Created a form:

   ```
   from passwords.fields import PasswordField
   class ResetForm(forms.Form):
     password = PasswordField(label="New password")
     confirmPassword = PasswordField(label="Confirm new password")
   ```
4. Added the form in my page
5. In settings.py added the field

   ```
   PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
   ```
6. Form shows up fine in the page. When i enter a password which is less than 6 characters, no error appears.

Is there a anything i am missing or anything i should do to get it to work ?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the template and the view?

Comment: In view to render, i have, render_to_response('templateName', {'resetForm': ResetForm). The template has : {{ resetForm }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is literarily as you typed in your comment, then the issue is with your code definition. From what you write, your view definition is:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('templateName', {'form': ResetForm})
```

You never instantiate the form and you new add the POST-data to the form. Change it to:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResetForm(data=request.POST)
    else:
        form = ResetForm()

    return render_to_response('templateName', {'form': form})
```

This should work :-).

Perhaps your better off using the `render` method for this includes a `RequestContext` object that handles the CSRF token.

More info on this subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: You literally saved me a ton of a time. I had totally missed out on the form.is_valid() check. After reading your comment, i went back to django docs and figured out what was missing. Thank you so much !